# React JS- TypeError: products.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my CartItem.js component:

```
const CartItem = (props) => {
  
    return (
        <div className="cart-item">
            <div className="right-block">
                <img className = "product-image"  alt="Product" />
            </div>
            <div className="left-block">
                <h3>{props.product.title}</h3>
                <div style = {{color: '#777'}}>Rs.{props.product.price}</div> 
                <div style = {{color: '#777'}}>Qty: {props.product.qty}</div>
                <div className="cart-item-buttons">
                   <img onClick = {() => props.onIncreaseQty(props.product)} className = "action-icons" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/992/992651.png" alt="" />
                   <img onClick = {props.onIncreaseQty} className = "action-icons" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/992/992683.png" alt="minus sign" />
                   <img className = "action-icons" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/3096/3096673.png" alt="delete icon" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CartItem;
```

and this my Cart.js component:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import CartItem from './CartItem'
import React from 'react'

const Cart = () => {
    
    const [products, setProducts] = useState(
             [
            {
            title: "Mobile",
            qty: 100,
            price: 9999,
            id: 1
            },
            {
            title: "Laptop",
            qty: 5,
            price: 99999,
            id:2
            },
            {
            title: "iPad",
            qty: 10,
            price: 90999,
            id:3
            }]
    )

        const handleIncreaseQuantity = (product) =>{
                console.log('please increase this n',product)
                const index = products.indexOf(product)
                products[index].qty += 1; 
                setProducts({products:products})
        }
    return (
        <div>
            {products.map((product) => 
               (<CartItem product = {product} onIncreaseQty = {handleIncreaseQuantity} key={product.id}/>)
            )}
         
        </div> );
}
 
export default Cart;
```

the UI is being rendered initially. But whenever I am trying to add an item using the + button, this error is being displayed:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vETY6.png)

I don't know what is wrong. I am using an array for the map function, I shouldn't get this error.

Comment: your setProducts should be like setProducts(products)

Comment: The state updater returned from `useState` is not the same as the class-based `setState`. `setState` accepts an object that it merges with the previous state. `useState` is not required to be an object, and accepts the new state **in its entirety**. You're changing the state into an object with a key called `products`.

Comment: You're also trying to pass `products` down as _`product`_ in the props for `Cart`.

Comment: thanks, but now the state is not being updated(the quantity is not increasing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `useState` hooks in the wrong way, your `useState` should expect the products array and you are passing the object of products.

your setProducts should be like `setProducts([...products]);`

Please check here working expample [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cdjxbw?file=src/Cart.js)

Comment: Desctructuring into the state updater without any additions is a code smell... The only reason I know of that this would make a difference is if you're mutating state elseware and the destructuring is there to trick React into re-rendering. This is what is happening here. They are mutating state, and covering it up with this.. It's a bad practice. Fix the real bug instead.

Answer (score 0):

The second value returned by useState is a function which can be used to set the state variable by calling it.

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState(
             [
            {
            title: "Mobile",
            qty: 100,
            price: 9999,
            id: 1
            },
            {
            title: "Laptop",
            qty: 5,
            price: 99999,
            id:2
            },
            {
            title: "iPad",
            qty: 10,
            price: 90999,
            id:3
            }]
    )

....

setProducts([1,2,3]); //will set products to [1,2,3]
```

You simply have to call `setProducts(products)` to update your state.